# Dokku static site built by webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, static, dokku

I'm trying to deploy a simple static site to Dokku, that uses webpack to bundle it's css. I added a `postinstall` script to my `package.json` that bundles all the data to `dist` folder after the dependencies installation which should bundle everything with every single deploy.

Dokku (probably) correctly decides to use the nodejs buildpack and installs node and npm. But when going to the app domain, it doesn't work.

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>   If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

So my question is, how do I say to Dokku, to start a static server from the `dist` folder, that is built by webpack?